# "Command buttons (?)" not working excel 2010

Tags: excel, commandbutton, office-2010

Im asking this question for my sister.
My sister is using someone's excel file to manage her business. The file contains [THESE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYpcY.png) buttons.

Now for some reason she can't get these buttons to work on her personal computer, but they do work on her computer at work. (I can't get them to work either)

I've searched most of the internet for solutions but all I came across was deleting all .exd file in the %temp% folder. This doesn't work either.

Now Im wondering if any of you have encountered this problem before and/or if you have a fix for it.

Many thanks,

Raigo

EDIT:
I can click the buttons, but they don't actually do anything

Comment: It's possible she has macros turned off.  Try turning enabling macros.

Comment: @tigeravatar I tried that... But it made no difference